# set operation on vector

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

I want do all set operation namely union, intersection, exclusive or and subtraction, on two vectors. How can I do that ?

Look link : [image for set operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/map/ref/polybool-venn.gif)

Comment: Use a set? Otherwise, what have you tried? What specifically aren't you managing to implement?

Comment: @EdChum, I hope you mean *standard library* algorithm?

Comment: @Griwes yes josuttis [pdf](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.josuttis.com%2Flibbook%2Falgolist.pdf&ei=3WSeT63VJYKr0QW-2IGNDw&usg=AFQjCNGOXfoVuxS9MOeFFrcGoi0bL0zYsA&sig2=6a42n8JvKQn9-K1t5dA-MA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest answer is to use the [standard library algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) `set_difference`, `set_union`, `set_intersection` etc.

However the drawback is that your input collections will need to be sorted and the elements will have to be comparible using `operator<` or a compare functor.

Comment: [Don't use cplusplus.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com)

Comment: @Griwes: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the ongoing debate, although I think a better approach would be to pressurise `cplusplus.com` to fix their site, if it's misleading. After all, it's still getting the highest rating on Google so, consequently, I'd suggest most C++ programmers are heading there for reference. Personally, I do like the example code on `cplusplus.com` - I learn best that way - and that seems to be lacking on quite a few other sites.

Comment: I've talked about that with many people, but all of them say that emails to cplusplus.com stuff doesn't work. And = their examples are, in many ways, wrong. First, `using namespace std;` is one of worse habits of crappy C++ programmer. Next, C-style includes are discouraged in C++ (I mean, `#include <stdio.h>` vs `#include <cstdio>` and so on). cppreference.com also provides code examples - in proper C++, to the contrary with cplusplus.com.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to sort the vectors (and keep them sorted).  Once you've done that, all of the operations you want are available in the standard library.